# Delphi IPWorks XMPP - Search for User

Tags: delphi, xmpp, ipworks

i use the TipwXMPP component from IPWorks to build my own XMPP-Client. Everythink works fine. But i found no way to search for users to add as Buddy.
With the exact ID i can add Buddies. But sometime User don't know the exact ID, so he should do a search for name like like any string.
In the components-methods i dont find any method that do this.

Can anybody help?
Thanks, Dieter

Comment: Standard XMPP users aren`t supposed to get/query user lists, only administrators are, and then it's still up to the server to support such requests. How did you do in the past what you plan now?

Comment: I haven't done that yet.  But the Pidgin program and also the Spark client support searching for users.  I use openfire as the server.  There should be a way to do this with the IPWorks component.  I also still have problems with sending files, as the transfer is immediately terminated with Success = false.  the reception goes however.